# How can there ever be an OOM scenario on Linux (heuristics behind OOM killer)?

Tags: linux, oom

I am aware of the concept of virtual memory. And with demand paging (depending on vm.overcommit_memory) you are able to allocate more memory than available RAM. Unless you "touch" a page nothing really happens. Else I guess there is a page fault and physical memory is used then for the page frame. But this somehow implies that if the system is tight on memory it will just page-out last recently used stuff and work normally.

How can there ever be the need to kill a process? Does it happen because too much memory is mlock()-ed. Is OOM invoked after there is too much trashing? Or to ask differently: what exactly are the heuristics behind triggering the OOM killer?

I read you could do "echo 1 > memory.oom_control" or "echo -17 > /proc/PID/oom_adj" to disable it. What are the implications of that? The machine will probably become totally unresponsive for a while. But if somehow the offending process detects it doesn't make progress it could also temporarily stop consuming memory (that fast) and eventually everything should start working again or am I mistaken?

In my scenario there is just one process (that has a huge in-memory cache). That data is not persistent of course, but I'd rather still not restart the process (and reload that data).

Comment: Yes, mlock prevents swap usage so the system may go OOM. Yes, if the system is thrashing and cannot page out fast enough it may go OOM. http://linux-mm.org/OOM covers other causes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be confused about how virtual memory and overcommitting are related.

Physical memory consists of the RAM chips in your computer. It is physically impossible to ever *use* more memory at the same time than you have physical memory. However, since the late 1970s out thereabouts there has been virtual memory, wherein the system will move some data from physical memory to disk, thereby storing memory that isn't actually being used away so physical memory can be used for other things. When this happens, programs cannot immediately use the data that was swapped out; when they try to do so anyway, the processor will generate a *page fault*, causing the operating system to load the required data from swap back into physical memory.

By using virtual memory, the total amount of in-flight data that can be in use is extended to the size of the physical memory plus the swap space. While this allows the system to run more programs at the same time, the amount of memory *actually in use* can never exceed the total available *virtual* memory (i.e., RAM + swap space)

In principle, the kernel should keep track of the amount of memory that programs have requested from it, and it should reject requests for more memory once its bookkeeping tells it that all memory has been *allocated*, even though not all of it may have been *used*. Most other kernels do this, and so they don't have an OOM killer (because they don't need one).

However, the system call for a program to allocate memory from the kernel doesn't allocate memory by the byte; it allocates it by larger blocks. In contrast, the actual implementation used by most programs to get memory (the `malloc()` C library function) *does* allow programs to allocate memory by the byte. What this means is that most programs, when they ask for some memory, will end up with `malloc()` allocating more than what they actually need. In addition, a good `malloc()` implementation will use some heuristics to keep smaller and larger allocations separate, so that memory fragmentation is not to bad, but doing so requires it to request more memory from the kernel, exacerbating the problem. As a result of these and other effects, without overcommitting, there will be large amounts of memory which are allocated but will *never* be used.

The idea of overcommitting is that you can safely allocate *some* more memory than the total amount of virtual memory your system has available without it backfiring. In essence, the kernel claims it allows an allocation, even though it *knows* it cannot live up to that promise, in the assumption that it won't need to live up to the full extent of those promises. However, the exact amount that can be overcommitted -- allocated -- without things ever going wrong cannot be predicted; so when the kernel detects that programs are trying to use all the memory they were allocated, the kernel will have to renege on its promises. This is where the OOM killer comes in.

Whether that is a good idea is up for debate. When the system runs out of memory, *something* is going to go wrong. If that's a case of some application trying to *allocate* more memory but the kernel having reserved everything already, then possibly that particular application is going to crash. If that just happens to be your X server, you're shit outta luck. At least if there's an OOM killer, it can decide which process to kill rather than things going bad after a bad allocation; and the OOM killer has some logic to avoid killing important processes, like your X server...

However, it you prefer, there are some sysctl knobs you can use to turn off overcommitting, it you think it's a bad idea.

Comment: Nice explanation, but not exactly what I asked for (yet). First confusion for me, isn't "virtual memory" basically infinite (or limited just by address space)? Of course you can't use more than RAM + swap then. But if you have a file backed page then throwing it out basically causes no harm 
except it will eventually have to be reloaded (which is very slow). For the others you might lose data (and swappiness setting is the correct balance here). What I want to say, the kernel doesn't ever need to break the promise it gave you. Unless that is safer than a process losing rarely used memory.

Comment: Theoretically, virtual memory is limited by address space, but in practice, it is limited by physical memory and available swap space.